# How to create a group of checkbox with JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

I want to create a group of checkbox ,but the user have the right to check just 3,
each checkbox represent a criteria of research in my  database(eg :if user check checkbox by priority I should concat this search criteria to my request SQL).
I have done some research in the internet but I have just found examples with ajax ,I dont want to use it.And I want to know should I use selectBooleanCheckbox OR selectManyCheckbox
Is there a simple example?

Answer (score 2):

JSF

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{myBean.values}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Value - 1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Value - 2" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Value - 3" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Bean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean{

    public String[] values;

        //getters setters

}
```

**Update:**

To print array values as mentioned in the example, you can have following util method

```
   public String getFavNumber3InString() {
    return Arrays.toString(favNumber3);
}
```

- [Reference](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-checkboxes-example/)

Comment: Hello again and thank you for the reply :) . I have followed your examlpe , but how can retrieve the result of check of each checkbox(checked or not). I have tried to port the result of check on another page result.jsp using:<h:outputText value="#{BeanTools.values}" />                                                but the result was: [Ljava.lang.String;@1194a34

Comment: You need to iterate through array.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `selectManyCheckbox`.  And here is a [simple example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-checkboxes-example/) for you to follow